# Python/C API: Statically-Linked Extensions?

Tags: compilation, static-libraries, static-linking, python-c-api

I've been writing a Python extension use the Python/C API to read data out of a .ROOT file and store it in a list of custom objects. The extension itself works just fine, however when I tried to use it on a different machine I ran into some problems.

The code depends upon several libraries written for the ROOT data manipulation program. The compiler is linking these libraries dynamically, which means I cannot use my extension on a machine that does not have ROOT installed.

Is there a set of flags that I can add to my compilation commands to make these libraries statically linked? Obviously this would make the file size much larger but that isn't much of an issue providing that the code runs at the same speed.

I did think about collating all of the ROOT libraries that I need into an 'archive' file. I'm not too familiar with this so I don't know if that's a good idea or not.

Any advice would be great, I've never really dealt with the static/dynamic library issue before.

Thanks, Sean.